# systemJS error with angular 2

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm trying to use an external library in my Angular2 application (https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/)

1. I npm installed the package
2. I imported directives in my TS file

And then it is not working, I have the following error :

```
system.src.js:4935 GET http://localhost:5000/ng2-material/all 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems to be a SystemJS error, but what can I do to make the directives working?

Comment: Does your config.js have map: {"ng2-material":"node_modules/ng2-material"}?

Comment: yes it have but it cannot resolve the 'All'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `ng2-material` library using NPM and then configure it within your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: false
      }
    },
    map: {
      'ng2-material': 'node_modules/ng2-material'
    }
  });
</script>
```